# Exchange mail working on iPhone but not Mac

Tags: exchange-server, outlook-web-app

I have my work email set up on an iPhone using the instructions given to me by my IT department. It works a treat.

I'd really like to be able to use in on my Mac. I have webmail (owa) access but it's a terrible webmail client. I use Airmail as my email client.

I've been reading online and I understand there are different issues with accessing Exchange email from a Mac, but I'm hoping they are surmountable.

The info from my IT people for iOS set up includes

My username
My password
A server - mobile.xxx.xxx.xx
A domain - live.xxxx.xxx.xx

I don't seem to be able to make any combination of these work for mac email setup.

Is there a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the stackexchange comunity. Please keep noted that Stackoverflow.com is a developer comunity. As you have a user and not developer question it must be placed in the correct community which is Superuser.com additional keep noted that the comunities normally not handle such questions. The best option would be to check that with your local IT as it could be that they do not support private MACs for security reasons or no 3rd party applications.

Answer (score -1):

Try to enter username with the domain:

```
domain\username 
username@domain.fullname.com
```

If nothing works, maybe you can ask your IT dept for help?

Also, your server administrator should check that **EWS** protocol is enabled for your mailbox (most MacOS clients works through this protocol)